# How do you create a custom video player on YouTube?

Tags: video, youtube, embed

According to the latest (September 16, 2011) instruction pages for YouTube,

`The easiest way to embed a playlist is to create a custom player. Go to your YouTube account and click "Custom Video Players", then "Create Custom Player".`

However, I can't find a place to click "Custom Video Players" anywhere on my account, or anywhere on the site. Does such a link really exist? Is the YouTube documentation up to date? If not, is there another way to create a custom video player to be embedded in another website?

Answer (score 2):

[From the Youtube docs, does this help?](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?&answer=171780)

> To embed a playlist, follow the steps below:
>
> Go to the Playlists section of your account. Select the playlist you'd
>   like to embed. Copy the embed code from the upper right corner. Paste
>   the code into your website or blog.

Comment: Well, I know how to embed a playlist that way; what I'm wondering about is this "custom player" YouTube is describing. (The piece I'm quoting is at `http://www.youtube.com/youtubeonyoursite`, by the way). What I'm wondering is whether this 'custom player' exists, or if YouTube is pointing to some out-of-date content on their own site.

Comment: That advice is also out-of-date or incorrect; the embed code is not in the "upper right corner". The button to get the embed code is on the upper left side of the page, to the right of the "Play All" button.
I'm guessing that YouTube has a lot of out-of-date documentation floating around and that the documentation I found refers to an old version oft the site.